# Is there a way to remove quotes from string

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove quotes from string in python.
For example,

I am trying to get ticker name through `equest.args.getlist('tickers')` that returns `'Infosys'` and which is fine

But there is a small issue here. There is a quote here so what happens in the next line is
`pd.read_sql_query('select  * from [dbo].' +str(tickers), engine)` which returns `select  * from [dbo].['Infosys']` and this is a problem... Actual statement should be `select  * from [dbo].[Infosys]` (without quotes). So can we remove quotes around Infosys string?

```
tickers = request.args.getlist('tickers')
data = pd.read_sql_query('select  * from [dbo].' +str(tickers), engine)
```

Comment: using f-string, for instance: `data = pd.read_sql_query(f'select  * from [dbo].[{str(tickers)}]', engine)`, however, using string concatenation to build SQL query is a bad choice...

Comment: Then what do u suggest ?:)

Comment: take a look at [SQL_injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In my experience, using ORM library is a better choice, which seems like that it isn't applicable for your circumstances. So maybe simple string concatenation works in your scenario.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion using f string, but did not work

Comment: It's possible that your `tickers` is actually `tickers="'InfoSys'"`, so f-string won't work. if `ticker="InfoSys"`, it should work. I suggest you to debug and find out the value of `ticker` and do some string slicing on it.

Comment: I tried.. its ````'InfoSys'```` only. FYI I am running  this logic is flask app using python... Not sure if I have to import any libraries

Comment: `x, y = "'infoSys'", "infoSys"`, `print(x, y)` => `'infoSys' infoSys`. If it's `InfoSys` only, print it shouldn't show quotes. BTW, Flask has nothing related to this and you don't need to import any packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you converted a list returned by `getlist()` into a string.

You should use `request.args.get()`, instead of `getlist()`, like this.

```
tickers = request.args.get('tickers')
```